# Is it possible to create just the descending index using Objectify?

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

In Objectify it is possible to create "partial indexes" just to add an index entry when necessary, for example:

```
@Index(IfNotNull.class)
private Date nextDate;
```

That will create two indexes entries, one in the ascending index and the second in the descending index.

I was wondering if there is a way to create an index that just update the descending or ascending index, but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is a current limitation of Google App Engine; you get both indexes or neither.